# How to calculate proportions for two sample t-test from data frame in R

Tags: t-test, proportion, r

I'd be very grateful for any help you can provide with this question - I've been using R for survival analysis, which has led on to a study looking at CMV reactivation - I initially started using time to CMV reactivation, but find that I really just need to look at the proportion of each group that reactivates CMV.

I need to compare the proportion of CMV reactivation in two groups to test for statistical significance.  The data is in the form of a data table, with individual rows for each patient, the columns being their properties (BMI is a continuous variable, CMV_risk_group has three discrete variables, CMV_reactivation is either 1 or 0).  The two groups are defined by:

> BMI>25&CMV_risk_group=1, subset=(CMV_risk_group>0) being TRUE
>
> BMI>25&CMV_risk_group=1, subset=(CMV_risk_group>0) being FALSE

I really need to be able to get this into a form where I can then apply the `prop.test()` function on them.

I've tried messing with tables/length/sum/aggregate, but to no avail.

In the future I will may also need to compare 4 groups of the above - BMI>25 true/false and CMV_risk_group=1 true/false - so any method that would also allow me do that would be also much appreciated!

Comment: You mention a t-test in the title. Could you explain how that comes in to the body of your question?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest included a minimal working example to show your data format & this seems more of a stackoverflow type question, that said make a new column: with the conditions you want

```
data.frame$group1<- BMI > 25 & CMV_risk_group == 1
```

This can be converted with as.numeric if you need 0 and 1 instead of True/False.

You can then subset as needed.